# Данные микроразметкой должны быть на каждой странице или дублироваться на все страницы сайта?

Tags: seo, schema.org

Есть сайт отельного типа. Хочу указать на сайте микроразметку.
Вопрос: Эта разметка должна быть на каждой странице(например в подвале) или хватает разместить только на одной, например "Главная страница".
Ниже привожу пример кода:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "Hotel",
    "name": "...",
    "address": {
        "@type": "PostalAddress",
        "streetAddress": "",
        "addressLocality": "",
        "addressRegion": "",
        "postalCode": ""
    },
    "email": "",
    "priceRange":"$"

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Общие руководящие принципы структурированных данных Гугл](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/sd-policies)** требуют, чтобы структурированные данные представляли **главное содержание** каждой, отдельной веб-страницы. Здесь ключевая фраза - главное содержание.

Каждая веб-страница имеет главное содержание отличное от других веб-страниц. Например, стартовая веб-страница имеет главное содержание с описанием какого-то отеля: название отеля, место расположение, международный рейтинг звезд (3 звезды или 4 звезды), **[уникальное торговое предложение](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)** (чем данный отель отличается от других, подобных отелей, в чем его изюминка/конфетка) и обязательно призыв к действию: *Посетите наш отель в каком-то уникальном месте или что-то подобное*. 
Соответственно м структурированные данные должны иметь разметку для типа **[Hotel](http://schema.org/Hotel)**. Однако обратите внимание, что в спецификации этого типа есть много свойств для структурированных данных, не только имя и адрес (как это указано в вашей разметке). Этот тип является уточняющим от типа **LocalBusiness**, поэтому можно использовать все свойства этого типа также. 
Если вы имеете ввиду конкретно структурированную разметку для отеля, то вам будет полезна документация **[Разметка для отелей](http://schema.org/docs/hotels.html)** от Схемы.

Для веб-страниц с описанием номеров отеля, имеет смысл применять разметку для типа **[Accommodation](http://schema.org/Accommodation)**.

Для веб-страницы Контакты, с юридической информацией о организации бизнеса, вероятно будет подходить разметка для типа **[Organization](http://schema.org/Organization)**.

Общее замечание: так как все веб-страницы имеют разное содержание, то и структурированные данные этих веб-страниц должны отражать их главное содержание и не быть дублированными. Если вы просто продублируете структурированные данные для всех веб-страниц, то Гугл, в лучшем случае проигнорирует это, а в худшем случае, если будет явное нарушение, то и забанит веб-страницу (-ы) или даже весь веб-сайт. Если вы создадите на одной веб-странице разметку для нескольких типов, то эти типы будут конкурировать и делить сок между собой.

Перед началом создания структурированных данных имеет смысл погрузиться в изучение руководства Гугл и в документацию Схемы.